# Clicar e fazer as opções desaparecerem com CSS

Tags: css

Eu clico em uma opção de uma caixa de opções do navbar, a página é aberta, mas esta caixa de opções permanece com o mouse sobre a opção escolhida:

Antes de clicar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de clicar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que depois do clique, a caixa de opções desapareça (quando eu clico, o mouse ainda fica sobre a opção e caixa permanece).

Como ajustar o `CSS` para fazer a caixa desaparecer após o clique? Código:

```
.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu { /*faz a caixa de opção cair*/
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a { /*configuração da caixa de opção*/
  display: block;
}
```

Não encontrei nenhuma propriedade que fizesse isso.

Comment: Quando tirar o mouse sobre o elemento `.dropdown` o hover deveria ser cancelado. Se isso não está acontecendo, provavelmente algum código JavaScript está forçando o menu ficar ativo.

Comment: Isso ocorre, @Sam.  Mas, eu quero que desapareça imediatamente após o clique.

Comment: Coloque a função que abre a página quando um item do menu é clicado. Acho que o problema e a solução tá nele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer fazer o menu ocultar após o click no link, com CSS você não vai conseguir. Tem que ocultar o menu dentro do evento que captura o click nos links do menu:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // cancela o evento do click
   $(".dropdown-menu")
   .hide() // esconde todos os menus
   .delay(100) // dá um atraso de 100ms
   .fadeOut(10, function(){ // fadeOut com callback para remover o display
      $(this).css("display", ""); // remove o display
   });
});
```

O `.hide()` irá esconder o menu, porém ele adiciona um atributo `style="display: none;"` ao elemento, e com isso o `:hover` do CSS não irá mais funcionar, porque o atributo `style` tem mais força que as regras do CSS. Por isso é preciso remover o `display: none;` do `style` adicionado; ou pode remover o próprio `style` se o elemento não tiver. É só trocar a linha:

```
$(this).css("display", "");
```

Por:

```
$(this).removeAttr("style");
```

## Usando eventos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`

A forma acima funciona bem em alguns navegadores, mas dá problema em outros (como o Edge e IE11). Nesses navegadores (inclusive no snippet daqui e no JSFiddle), quando o menu é escondido, o cursor do mouse continua ativo sobre o link (talvez seja um bug) fazendo com que o menu volte a aparecer.

Uma forma mais funcional seria usando os eventos acima citados no lugar do CSS `:hover`:

```js
$(".dropdown").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
   $(".dropdown-menu", this)[e.type == "mouseenter" ? "show" : "hide"]();
});

$(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // cancela o evento do click
   $(".dropdown-menu")
   .hide() // esconde todos os menus
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
   Menu1
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">op1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">op2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
   Menu2
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="">op1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">op2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```